# script command map to related java code in MongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have an aggregation command in script console as below,

```
> db.examSessionCol.aggregate( [ { $group : { _id : "$examinationId", avgScore: {$avg: "$score"}, co
unt: { $sum: 1 } } } ] )
```

Here is the result,

```
{ "_id" : NumberLong(4), "avgScore" : 81.4, "count" : 5 }
{ "_id" : NumberLong(1), "avgScore" : 17.2, "count" : 40 }
```

I need to apply it into my java based project, I found there is little documents about usage of aggregation in MongoTemplate, could anyone help me how I can write the related java code with good performance?

Following is the return object:

```
public class ExamParticipatedItem {
    protected int examinationId;
    protected int count;
    protected double avgScore;
}
```

And the method written by me but doesn't work currently,

```
public List<ExamParticipatedItem> getExamParticipatedItems() {
    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(ExaminationSession.class, GroupOperationBuilde), ExamParticipatedItem.class, collectionName).getMappedResults();//it's not completed
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer for this project and solution is from [this document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation):

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(ExaminationSession.class,
        group("examinationId").first("examinationId").as("examinationId").avg("score").as("avgScore").count().as("count"));
List<ExamParticipatedItem> aggregationresults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collectionName, ExamParticipatedItem.class)
        .getMappedResults();
```